# Sorting speed in python consistently inconsistent

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I was writing a python program to test out two different versions of quicksort. I then decided to compare the same version with itself, just for fun. I was very surprised to find out that, every time I tried it out, the version lower in the code was faster. I then replaced my scrappy quicksort implementation with the python sorting function. The same trend continued! Does anyone know why this is?

```
import random
from time import clock

randlist = lambda: [random.random() for i in range(random.randint(5, 100))]
n = 10000
sum1 = 0
sum2 = 0
for i in range(n):
    l = randlist()

    before1 = clock()
    sorted(l)
    sum1 += clock() - before1

    before2 = clock()
    sorted(l)
    sum2 += clock() - before2

print("first go  ", sum1 / n)
print("'second go", sum2 / n)
```

This code outputs the following (its mostly the same):

```
first go  9.162100000000225e-06
second go 8.210699999999926e-06
```

I only tried it on my machine. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 3.4 on an i7-2670QM.

**EDIT:** I just the same phenomenon appears when both "sorted(l)" lines are comented out! The only difference is, both times are 10 times lower.

Comment: Note: This is not a normal way of testing code performance.  A much better approach would be to use the built-in [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) library, specifically [`timeit.timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html#timeit.timeit).  The library has been specifically engineered and thoroughly tested to yield the best accuracy.

Comment: timeit is great, but to find out the detail use a profiler. Python has a native profiler.

Comment: @CppLearner - I assumed that the OP just wanted an overall estimate.  But yes, a profiler would be good too.  Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Comment: You're using global variables, which are stored in a dict. It is possible that some variable name causes a hash collision, so the corresponding variable is ever-so-slightly slower to access. You could test this by swapping the code blocks being timed.

Comment: @kindall But the code blocks are the same!

Comment: Not exactly. The result of `clock()` is stored in `before1` or `before2` *after* the call to `clock()`. So you are counting that in the time.